# Median and Mean of Sum of Two Exponentials

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, exponential-function, exponential-sum

I have a cumulative distribution function:
$$G(x) = -ae^{-xb} - ce^{-xd}+h$$
The associated probability density function is:
$$g(x) = abe^{-xb} + cde^{-xd}$$
My problem concerns $x\ge 0, X \in R$.

I know that the mean (expected value) of $x$ can be computed by:
\begin{align}
E[x] &= \int_0^{\infty} x g(x)~dx \\
&=\int_0^{\infty}xabe^{-xb}~dx~+~\int_0^{\infty}xcde^{-xd}~dx\\
&=\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}
\end{align}

The median is when $G(x) = 0.5$. This requires finding the roots of
$$
0 = -ae^{xb} - ce^{xd}+h-0.5
$$
Based on the Abel–Ruffini theorem I know that there are no general solutions to this problem.

My question relates to the component exponential decay equations contained in $G(x)$:
\begin{align}
F(x) &= ae^{xb}\\
J(x) &= ce^{xd}
\end{align}

The mean of $F(x)$ is $\frac{a}{b}$ and median $\frac{a\ln2}{b}$. The mean of $J(x)$ is $\frac{c}{d}$ and median $\frac{c\ln2}{d}$.

**MY QUESTION:
The ratio of the mean of $g(x)$ to the mean of $f(x)$ is**
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} \div \frac{a}{b}$$
**But is the ratio of the MEDIAN of $g(x)$ TO THE MEDIAN of $f(x)$ the same? I am assuming not, because there is no generic formula to solve for the median of $g(x)$. But I don't know how to prove this, so am not sure.**

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct, the ratio of mean to median of a random variable $X$ with density of shape $abe^{-ax}+cde^{-cx}$ is not always the same as the ratio of mean to median of an exponentially distributed random variable. (The latter ratio, as your post pointed out, is $\frac{1}{\ln 2}$.)

To show this, it is enough to give an example. Let $X$ have density function $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-x}+2e^{-2x}\right)$ (for $x\gt 0$). The mean of $X$ is $\frac{3}{4}$. To compute the median, we solve the equation 
$$\frac{1}{2}(2-e^{-m}-e^{-2m})=\frac{1}{2}.$$
This is one of the rare cases where we can compute explicitly: $m=\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$. The golden section strikes again.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I am interested in the ratio of the mean of the combined exponential to the single exponential; and the ratio of the median of the combined exponential to the single exponential. I updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: There has been no essential change in the question. Let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be the two means, and $m_1,m_2$ the two medians. To ask whether $\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}=\frac{m_1}{m_2}$ is the same as asking whether $\frac{\mu_1}{m_1}=\frac{\mu_2}{m_2}$